# Получить два значения из функции

Tags: c++, vector

Мне нужно получить из этой функции два значения a*b и a*a. Как сделать чтобы функция вызывалась один раз и получала на выходе два значения типа double?

```
double dot_product(vector<double> a, vector<double> b) {
double res = 0.0;
//#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res)
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    res += a.at(i) * b.at(i);
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: Функция по определению может вернуть только одно значение. Вариантов у вас два: 1) сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала структуру из двух полей типа double; 2) передать в качестве параметров два указателя или две ссылки на переменные типа double, и писать результат туда.

Comment: Я бы передавал вектора по ссылке - зачем их копировать? `double dot_product(const vector<double>& a, const vector<double>& b)`

Answer (score 1):

Структурно не поддерживаю идею вопроса.
Но ответ в лоб - используйте кортежи  (std::tuple).

Comment: Почему именно кортежи? У ТС оба значения одного типа.

Answer (score 0):

Два значения из функции можно вернуть используя указатели:

```
void myFunc(double* a, double* b)
{
 *a = 2.12;
 *b = 3.14;
}
void main()
{
 double a, b;
 myFunc(&a, &b);
//теперь а = 2,12 b = 3.14
}
```